# Как распознать что на изображении?

Tags: java, графика

нужно распознать какая геометрическая фигура на изображении. Для этого у нас есть шаблоны: круг, треугольник и квадрат. Далее передаем изображение и программа должна сказать на какую фигуру она похожа. Проблема в том, что находит неправильно. Сперва добавляю изображения, передаю в массив(pixels) затем нахожу совпадение с шаблонами, после результат.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Map<String, Image> mymap = new HashMap<String, Image>();
        //Создаем изображения
        Image square = new Image("C:\\Java\\projectImage\\src\\img\\R.png");
        Image circle = new Image("C:\\Java\\projectImage\\src\\img\\circle.png");
        Image triangle = new Image("C:\\Java\\projectImage\\src\\img\\tr.png");
        Image myImage = new Image("C:\\Java\\projectImage\\src\\img\\myTrian.png");

        // Вывод в консоль
        square.printMatrix();
        System.out.println();
        circle.printMatrix();
        System.out.println();
        triangle.printMatrix();
        System.out.println();
        myImage.printMatrix();

        // Сохраняем изображения в хранилище 
        mymap.put("Square", square);
        mymap.put("Circle", circle);
        mymap.put("Triangle", triangle);
        mymap.put("My Image", myImage);


        // Находим схожи или нет
        square.findSimilarity(square.pixels, myImage.pixels);
        System.out.println();
        circle.findSimilarity(circle.pixels, myImage.pixels);
        System.out.println();
        triangle.findSimilarity(triangle.pixels, myImage.pixels);

        int num = 500;
        String res = "";

        // Выявляем на что похоже
        for (Map.Entry<String, Image> pair : mymap.entrySet()) {
           if (pair.getKey() != "My Image"){
               if (pair.getValue().similarity < num){
                   num = pair.getValue().similarity;
                   res = pair.getKey();
               }
           }
        }

        System.out.println("Answer - " + res);

    }
}
```

Класс Image

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class Image {
    File file;
    BufferedImage image; 
    int[][] pixels;
    int similarity = 0;

    Image(String path) throws IOException{
        file = new File(path);
        image = ImageIO.read(file);
        pixels = new int[image.getHeight()][image.getWidth()];
    }



    void printMatrix() {

        for(int i=0; i<image.getHeight(); i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<image.getWidth(); j++) {
                if(image.getRGB(i,j) != -1) {
                    System.out.print(" " + '0');
                    pixels[i][j] = 0;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print(" " + '1');
                    pixels[i][j] = 1;
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }


    }

    void findSimilarity(int[][] arrayA, int[][] arrayB) {

        for(int i=0; i<image.getHeight(); i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<image.getWidth(); j++) {
                if (arrayA[i][j] == arrayB[i][j]){
                    similarity++;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Similarity: " + similarity);
    }


    public File getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public BufferedImage getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(BufferedImage image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public int[][] getPixels() {
        return pixels;
    }

    public void setPixels(int[][] pixels) {
        this.pixels = pixels;
    }
}
```

Comment: проясните критерий схожести, если это четкое попиксельное совпадение с оригиналом, то у меня для вас плохие новости детектировать таким образом, что-либо кроме оригинала невозможно.

Comment: Сравнивать планировал по пикселям. А если считать количество нулей или единиц и там где больше выводить за результат ?

Comment: У вас классическая задача [классификации](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8) вместе с "машинным" зрением, я не знаю других способов решения подобного рода задач, кроме как использовать нейронные сети.